# Scrolling down a menu and clicking on an element clicks on the wrong element

Tags: java, selenium

In my web driver test I'm scrolling down a list of menu items and clicking it. But what I observe is that it actually navigates to a wrong link which means it has the effect of clicking some menu item at the top of the menu. Why does this happen?

```
// Click menu button that launches menu.
driver.findElement(By.className("menuButton")).click();

// Scroll down the menu.
new Actions(driver)
    .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.className("navMenu")))
    .click()
    .sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    .perform();

// Find and click a menu item now visible.
new Actions(driver)        
    .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("bottom menu item")))
    .click()
    .perform();
```

Comment: Could you please avoid ".sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)" and try

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `Actions` for something like this. Just `driver.findElement(By.linkText("bottom menu item").click()` it. ... after removing the `PAGE_DOWN` call as Pritam suggested.

Comment: How could I avoid sending page down? navMenu is my menu, it is not the scollbar. The items in the navMenu exceed the viewport so I send page down to scroll down.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure there is no another bottom menu item start with same "bottom menu item" text and placed previous to your element.

You can also try to scroll using Javascript and `scrollIntoView` method, if click not working by itself:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

// Click menu button that launches menu.
driver.findElement(By.className("menuButton")).click();

driver.findElement(By.className("navMenu")).click();

// Find and click a menu item now visible.
WebElement bottomMenuItem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("bottom menu item"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", bottomMenuItem);
bottomMenuItem.click();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any error but it clicks on the wrong link whose link text is different from what I've asked.

Comment: Share html of the menu

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Nu3bzgdk My menu item of interest is the one with href="./supermarket/mydomainapps"

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Click menu button that launches menu.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("menuButton")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("navMenu")).click();
```

Step 2.

```
WebElement bottomMenuItem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("bottom menu item"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", bottomMenuItem);
```

Note - There could be some micro seconds delay before "bottom menu item". So there could be chances at some point it could fail clicking on "bottom menu item". So you may would need to wait for a second to make this action more reliable without facing failure in future.

Comment: Are you saying there is some difference in clicking bottomMenuItem using javascript instead of in webdriver?

Comment: I said it because in case u r not using implicit wait and link "bottom menu item" may take micro second time before getting ready to any such click. I would suggest you try to give 1-2 sec of delay before performing Java script click on it. Let's know please.

Comment: After scrolling the menu using driver.findElement(By.className("navMenu")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN); and finding the menu item of interest by linkText, I have added a sleep for 2 seconds and then tried clicking it, but it still clicks the wrong menu item.

Comment: Okay then probably u need to change locator linkText approach. Please share html of the menu to understand the structure.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Nu3bzgdk My menu item of interest is the one with href="./supermarket/mydomainapps"

Comment: Please try using xpath just to ensure, changing locator strategy would be able to locate element or not  WebElement bottomMenuItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'RunitnowstorenavmenuMyDomainApps')]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", bottomMenuItem);